# How to use a fitted model parameters for forecasting other time series

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, arima

I have fitted an ARIMA(1,1,2) to time series `TS1` as below:

```
arima112 <- arima(TS1, c(1,1,2))
```

Now I want to use the coefficients of AR and MA that I got from `arima112` to forecast another time series (`TS2`). How can I apply the `arima112` model on `TS2`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have a fitted `arima` model, you can apply it to another time series without re-estimating using

```
refit <- Arima(newdata, model=fit)
```

The `Arima` function is part of the `forecast` package: [Reference](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/forecast.pdf)

Comment: thanks for your response, however `Arima` is *not* R base function so you also should provide reference to library that contains the function since there is few thousand packages on CRAN and without reference someone may be unable to find the function.

Answer (score 3):

You should already have a `predict()` function that can accept new data (see `?predict.arima0`). Though, there is a nice R package built for forecasting with ARIMA models called [`forecast`](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/index.html) that I recommend you play with a bit as well.

To forecast using the same parameters on different data, you might try "refitting" the same model on new data but *fix* the parameters (using the `fixed` argument to `arima()`) at the values you estimated on a different data set. Then an arima object is returned with which you can use the available forecasting methods.

Comment: Thank you, I know how to use predict or forecast functions for a certain time series but I want to use model parameters for another time series and I don't know how to save coefficients and apply them on another time series.

Comment: @Fred Sorry I missed the detail. See added comments.