# Predict from estimated ARIMA model with new data

Tags: r, forecasting, arima, anomaly-detection

Suppose I have a training dataset, I use `auto.arima` (from "forecast" package in R) to fit the training data. As a result I get the lag and integration orders $(p, d, q)$ and the corresponding coefficients $\psi_i$ and $\theta_i$.

```
ytrain = c(0.435477843, 0.435394762, 0.195528995, 1.451623315, 1.740084831 2.379904714, 1.092366508, 0.001031411, 0.592164090, 0.670323418)

fit <- auto.arima(ytrain)
```

Now I have new data

```
ytest = c(-0.1349199  0.9001208 -0.5171740 -0.9958452  0.4125953 -0.3320575  0.1633313  0.2890109 -0.4284824  0.7902680)
```

I want to fit this new data by using the model from training data (using the same $(p, d, q)$ and also the same corresponding coefficients). I.e. I want to use the model I have from `ytrain` to make prediction based on `ytest`. As a result I can know if there are any points in the new data looking like anomaly points (compared to the training data)

I have searched long time and haven't find a R function to implement it. I know I can compute this by hand, e.g. for ARMA(1,2):

$$\hat{Y}_n =  \hat{\mu} + \hat{\psi}_1 Y_{n-1} - \hat{\theta}_{1} \epsilon_{n-1} - \hat{\theta}_2 \epsilon_{n-2}.$$

But if I do this, I am not sure how to start to get $\epsilon_1 = Y_1 - \hat{Y}_1$ and $\epsilon_2 = Y_2 - \hat{Y}_2$ to start since I don't have $\hat{Y}_1$ and $\hat{Y}_2$.

- Could anyone suggest an R function for doing this? Or if not,
- Could anyone help me with this question if there is no R function doing this?

Comment: I was going through my old answers and noticed this one was not accepted. Do you perhaps need further clarification?

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you are not looking for **multiple-step-ahead** forecasts from the model estimated on the original data set (this is very easy to do with [`forecast.Arima`](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/forecast/docs/forecast.Arima) or [`predict`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/predict.html); you should have been able to figure that out by yourself).

I suppose you want to **incorporate the new values** as they come (but without reestimating the model) and use them in place of predicted values to produce **one-step-ahead** forecasts.

Using your own example, I suppose you do **not** want

$$ \hat{Y}_{t+1} =  \hat{\mu} + \hat{\psi}_1 \hat Y_{t} - \hat{\theta}_{1} \hat\epsilon_{t} - \hat{\theta}_2 \hat\epsilon_{t-1} $$

but **rather** (*check out tildes and hats carefully*)

$$ \tilde{Y}_{t+1} =  \hat{\mu} + \hat{\psi}_1      Y_{t} - \hat{\theta}_{1} \tilde\epsilon_{t} - \hat{\theta}_2 \hat\epsilon_{t-1} $$

where $\hat\epsilon_{t}=0$ (based on model prediction **not** using the new value $Y_t$) while $\tilde\epsilon_{t}=Y_t-\hat Y_t$ (based on the actual value versus a prediction).

This thread tells you how to refit your model on completely new data: ["How to use a fitted model parameters for forecasting other time series"](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55937/how-to-use-a-fitted-model-parameters-for-forecasting-other-time-series).

Based on that idea, you can

1. append the original data set with the new observations, one at a time;
2. refit the model (without reestimating it);
3. forecast one step ahead.

Also, if you are doing things by hand, the model fitted on a sample spanning $1,\dotsc,T$ gives you fitted values $\hat Y$ and $\hat\epsilon$ all the way up to $T$, so obtaining them should be no problem.

Comment: You're maybe right, but he said "I want to fit this new data by using the model from training data (using the same (p,d,q)(p,d,q) and also the same corresponding coefficients). I.e. I want to use the model I have from ytrain to make prediction based on ytest". So ..

Comment: @elJosso, you might be right. But that is only the better for you as you have posted an answer based on that idea. Let us wait until the OP reacts, and I will happily upvote your answer if that is what he actually needed.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Really appreciate it. I have looked at the thread you give me. But I am not sure what  is this "refit <- Arima(newdata, model=fit) " actually doing.  Does it fit new data with same model but find different coefficients? Maybe I haven't phrased my question clearly. What I am doing is to detect anomaly segment of new data using ARIMA method. Given training data, I got the model (p, d, q) and coefficients. Given another test data, I used (p,d,q) and coefficients from the previous model to refit the data within the range not prediction.

Comment: @Richard Hardy is correct. But the index t should be from 1 to n, instead of n+1. I suppose the meaning of tilde is fitting new data with information from training data. What I need is $\tilde{Y}_1$ ,.... $\tilde{Y}_n$ conditional on p,d,q $\psi_i$ $\theta_i$ from training data.

Comment: Suppose I want to do it by hand. For ARMA(p, q) model. Suppose $w = max(p,q)$, I need $\epsilon_1$,...,$ \epsilon_w$ to find fitted value from $\hat{Y}_{w+1}$,... $\hat{Y}_n$. How to initialize these $\epsilon_1$,...,$ \epsilon_w$? I have tried set them to zero, but the result is different from fitted() from R.

Comment: `refit ...` keeps the model order and the coefficient values. It produces fitted values and residuals from the new data, that is the only thing it does. Then you can see how far the fitted values are from the real values and look for outliers. Now regarding doing it by hand for $n+1, n+2, \dotsc$, you have to take the residuals from the fitted model and use them where needed. I do not see why you care about fitted values within the original sample; they are not needed for forecasting out of sample or in any other way relevant for outlier detection in the new sample.

Comment: From the original sample you only need the last $q$ residuals $\hat\epsilon_{t-q+1},\dotsc,\hat\epsilon_{t}$ to be able to predict out of sample with the fitted model. That you readily get as the output of the ARMA model on the original sample. Probably there was some confusion with time indexing: I am using 1 to $t$ (or 1 to $n$) for the original sample and $t+1,t+2,\dotsc$ ($n+1,n+2,\dotsc$) for the new sample.

Answer (score -1):

I think you are looking for this method, aren't you ?

### An example of ARIMA forecasting ( with ARIMA from package [Stats](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/stats/html/predict.arima.html)):

`predict(fit, 10)`

### An example of ARIMA forecasting ( with ARIMA from package [forecast](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/forecast/docs/auto.arima)):

`forecast(fit,h=10)
forecast(fit,10)$fitted`

So you are forecasting 10 steps on your model

When you are using a package think about read the doc : https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/forecast/forecast.pdf.
   There is a LOT of informaton inside

Comment: That was not the question