# Fitted ARIMA on new time series

Tags: arima

Based on the accepted answer from this post: [How to use a fitted model parameters for forecasting other time series](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/55937/how-to-use-a-fitted-model-parameters-for-forecasting-other-time-series), it is possible to use a fitted ARIMA model for forecasting another time series. What are some good reasons reasons for doing that? Can for example someone create a model and then given a new time series use it to produce predictions (that reminds more of how a LSTM works, not an ARIMA)? Lastly, how the new time series should look like for it to work, should it have the length of the original time series or maybe that of a seasonal period?